# How is it possible that the AVR microarchitecture can fetch 2 operands from the GP-Register to the ALU in only 1 clock cycle?

Tags: assembly, cpu-architecture, avr, micro-architecture

According to the Datasheets of AVR Microcontroller, as well as the Datasheet of the Instruction Set from the AVR architecture, certain instructions, for example `ADD`, can fetch 2 operands stored in the GP-Registers during only 1 Clock transition to the ALU. The Instruction-Word for the `ADD` instruction includes 2 addresses for GP-Registers; each 5 Bit wide, one for destination/source and one for source. But how is this implemented on a Hardware Level? Wouldn't the 5 Bits for the 2 Register interfere with each other as they are trying to access the GP-Register through the same Direct Addressing Bus?

Comment: [Note how the AVR register file supports two reads in a single clock](https://microchipdeveloper.com/8avr:avrcore).  From a logical POV this is a form of multiport register file. As the AVRs have slow clocks, the multiport can be implemented in a number of ways: either by [making the circuit more complex](https://www.idt.com/document/apn/253-introduction-multi-port-memories-0) or by naively multiply the external clock (so that the reading is not actually a single clock operation), for example. I wasn't unable to find any reserved information on how AVR cores are acually implemented.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Multi-ported register files are widely used in CPU designs**.  [As wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_file):

> Modern integrated circuit-based register files are usually implemented by way of **fast static RAMs with multiple ports**.

A quick google search found [some slides](http://icslwebs.ee.ucla.edu/yang/classwiki/images/7/7e/15b_ee215b_registerfile.pdf) with some gate / transistor level details about a multi-ported SRAM cell, and block diagrams of how to build a register file out of that.

**This is not at all unique to AVR**.  Pipelined RISC CPUs in general are designed around executing (at least) 1 instruction per clock when nothing stalls, with the register file handling 2 reads + 1 write per cycle.  e.g. MIPS and other [classic 5-stage RISC pipelines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classic_RISC_pipeline).  AVR is just an 8-bit version of those ideas.

---

[@Margaret Bloom pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59641817/how-is-it-possible-that-the-avr-microarchitecture-can-fetch-2-operands-from-the#comment105445947_59641817) that multi-ported register files aren't the only implementation strategy.  Given AVR's slow clock speed, the register file could be single-ported and simply clocked faster.

---

Modern superscalar CPUs have even wider register files.

For example, (https://www.agner.org/optimize/blog/read.php?i=857) Intel Skylake can sustain a throughput of reading at least 7 GP-integer registers per clock cycle, and at the same time write 3 registers in the same clock cycle.  (And write FLAGS 3 times, thanks to register renaming breaking the WAW (write-after-write) hazard.  Although this doesn't really count as separate; uops that produce a register and a FLAGS output can use the same physical register entry to hold both.  The RAT keeps track of what comes from where.)

(Different loops can easily write 4 registers per clock cycle on modern Intel; the  experiment I linked was mainly testing how many register reads I could get per clock, and unfused-domain uop throughput.)